# How can I perform a task after user defined amount of minutes?

Tags: android, service, timer, runnable, alarm

I am making some sort of timer, which uses a `Service` to define a `Runnable` which is being ran after the user defined amount of minutes. The problem is that when the user defined amount of minutes is about (or higher than) 120 minutes, it seems the system forgets about the `Runnable`, and doesn't perform the tasks in there.

My question is: Is there a better way to schedule tasks to be ran after a specified amount of time?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use alarm manager to trigger the event after some time  refer here http://www.learn-android-easily.com/2013/06/scheduling-task-using-alarm-manager.html

Comment: Thanks, I will look into this when I get home... Seems easy, almost too easy.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I needed. I managed to work it out, and works flawlessly. I'll update my post with the code.